# How do I remove a trailing whitespace from a string without certain functions?

Tags: python

I need to remove whitespace from a str() output in an assignment because of my code. How do I do so without using str.strip() or similar functions? My code is as follows:

```
r, c, p, a, std, b = 0, 0, 0, '', input('Standard game? (y/n): '), ' '
if std == 'y':
    r, c = 6, 7
else: 
    r, c = int(input('r? (2 - 20): ')), int(input('c? (2 - 20): '))
if r < 11 and c < 11:
    a = str(r-1)
    for i in range (r-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + ' ' + str('·')
        print(a)
        a = str(i-1)
    for j in range (c):
        b = b + ' ' + str(j)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Use a string slice.

Comment: Which string are you trying to remove trailing spaces from?

Comment: Explicit loop. Start with the right character and remove spaces until you encounter a non-space character.

Comment: Barmar: Every single line has an excess trailing white space

Comment: You mean the lines that you're creating with the concatenation? Why don't you avoid adding the trailing spaces in the first place?

Comment: Because I don't know how to avoid it

Comment: Put your data in a list and use `" ".join(listvar)`

Comment: That is not allowed

Comment: You need to be clearer about the rules in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```
your_string = "test "

print("#" + your_string[:-1] + "#")
```

#### Output

```
#test#
```

Comment: What if the string has more than one space at the end?  Or what if it has a space at the beginning?

Comment: @JohnGordon The question just says trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/) :)

```py
import re 

s1 = "asdf       "
s2 = "asdf\t"
s3 = "as   df"
s4 = "  as   df"
s5 = "asdf"
def strip(s):
    return re.sub("\s*$", "", s)
    
for s in (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5):
    print(f">{s}<\t>{strip(s)}<")
```

### Output

```
>asdf       <   >asdf<
>asdf   <       >asdf<
>as   df<       >as   df<
>  as   df<     >  as   df<
>asdf<  >asdf<
```

This regular expression replaces all instances of zero or more whitespace characters before the end of the line (`\s+$`) with an empty string (`""`). As shown by `s3` and `s4`, whitespace in the middle of the string will not be affected.

Answer (score -1):

Use `join()` and a comprehension to assemble a new copy of the string and omit spaces.

```
s = " something      "
s_no_spaces = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch != ' ')
```

Or use split() and keep only the first result:

```
s_no_spaces = split(s)[0]
```

Comment: This removes all spaces, not just trailing spaces.

Comment: @Barmar the first sentence of the question is "I need to remove whitespace".

Comment: The title does specify "trailing whitespace".